# how to use useState Hook in react native with styled component

Tags: react-native, styled-components

i'm working react native project with styled component. i tried to use a state hook to an active element. it's a category bar. i want a different background when an element is active

```
     const [active, setActive] = useState('All');

  const Keywords = [
    'All',
    'React js',
    'React Native',
    'use of API',
    'Redux',
    'Gospel',
  
  ];

  const handlePress = value => {
    setActive(value);
  };

  return (
    <Container
      horizontal
      bounces={false}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {Keywords.map((value, i) => (
        <ButtonText onPress={() => handlePress(value)} key={i} active>
          <Content>{value}</Content>
        </ButtonText>
      ))}
    </Container>
  );
};





    const ButtonText = styled.TouchableOpacity`

     background-color: #e6e6e6;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-left: 5px;
     border-width: 1px;
     border-radius: 20px;
     border-color: #4c4c4c;
     background-color: transparent;
`;
```

can you help me find this solution.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
styles={[styles.defaultStyle, active ? styles.activeStyle: null]}
```

just define the styles after

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   defaultStyle: {backgroundColor: 'e6e6e6'},
   activeStyle: {bacgkroundColor: 'black'}
})
```